# MySQL multiple elemnts match where (A, B, Z) IN (A,B,C,E,Z)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a `MySQL` query that gets all rows in the database that have ALL the tags given.

At the moment I have this:

```
 WHERE "tag1" IN (SELECT tag FROM tag_list WHERE client.id = tag_list.id)
```

This works fine for **one tag** but if I have multiple tags I don't want to copy paste this query many times and join them with `AND` because it seems slow to select all tags multiple times.

Is there any way I can do something like this?

```
 WHERE ("tag1", "tag2", "tag3") IN (SELECT tag FROM tag_list WHERE client.id = tag_list.id)
```

Meaning that my client has all the tags: **tag1, tag2, tag3**.

If I try to execute the last query I get this error: `Operand should contain 3 column(s)`.

So, my current solution would be something like this:

```
WHERE "tag1" IN (SELECT tag FROM tag_list WHERE client.id = tag_list.id)
AND "tag2" IN (SELECT tag FROM tag_list WHERE client.id = tag_list.id)
AND "tag3" IN (SELECT tag FROM tag_list WHERE client.id = tag_list.id)
```

Which doesn't seem optimal at all.

Tables structure:

```
client [id, name]
tag_list [FK id references client.id, tag]
```

So each client can have multiple tags, and I want to only retrieve the clients that have ALL the given tags.

Comment: Can't you use `SELECT * FROM client  LEFT JOIN tag_list ON tag_list.id = client.id WHERE tag1 IS NOT NULL and tag2 IS NOT NULL and tag3 IS NOT NULL`

Comment: `tag1` is not a column name, is the value of a row inside the `tag_list` table at column `tag`

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860162/mysql-select-groups-having-values-covering-a-set.

Comment: And, just to mention that this is a small part of a larger query. And that the number of tags is not constant, but given as a parameter, so not necessary for 3 tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the subquery and you should be good:

```
JOIN tag_list tag1 ON client.id = tag1.id AND tag1.tag = "tag1"
JOIN tag_list tag2 ON client.id = tag2.id AND tag2.tag = "tag2"
JOIN tag_list tag3 ON client.id = tag3.id AND tag3.tag = "tag3"
```

I can't really think of a more efficient way to do this. Mysql should be able to optimize this easily.

Comment: That won't necessarily be faster then several `IN()`

Comment: but it could be faster then my `HAVING` part. and I can't see any *several IN()* there is just one.

Comment: I was talking about the OP question, he said the several `IN()` doesn't seem optimized

Comment: I think the real problem is not server `IN()` but the fact that I compute a new `SELECT` for each `IN()`, maybe that table could be cached somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `WHERE` with `INNER JOIN` like:

```
INNER JOIN tag_list 
ON client.id = tag_list.id
 AND  tag_list.tag IN ("tag1","tag2","tag3")
```

**UPDATE** and if I got you correctly, and you want to get only clients with all 3 tags together:

```
INNER JOIN tag_list 
ON client.id = tag_list.id
 AND  tag_list.tag IN ("tag1","tag2","tag3")
GROUP BY client.id
HAVING COUNT(DICTINCT tag_list.tag)=3
```

Comment: That will be a problem if this is a part of a bigger query

Comment: @sagi could you point to the problem you see with some details?

Comment: Yes, lets say he needs 10 other columns, from 4 different tables, how would he do that group by? You changed his query, without seeing the actual one, how can you be sure he will be able to make this change by him self?

Comment: If he needs 4 different tables and 10 other columns, that would be 100% another question. and you never can guess what OP need. from what OP provided my answer is 100% correct

Comment: I never said your answer is wrong, I pointed out that if he is dealing with a larger query, he might have problems using this method, unlike @sba and my solution.

Comment: @sagi your solution is not solution at all. at least because it will never run. check the syntax first ;-)